# Which VS (2015) file contains an infirmation about the structure of solution explorer?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, gitignore, git-extensions, solution-explorer

I'm working with Git.Trying to pull the VS progect from repository through GitExtantions. Everything's going fine but one thing - the file structure of Solution Explorer Window. An original project in repository has different  structure in Solution Explorer. I mean all files are the same, but in original project in repository they are located in different folders that i created at start. It's very convenient to work with it. And after pulling the project I lost this structure and have just the whole list of files whithout any correlation folders. 
In .gitignore file there are these types of files:

```
    Thumbs.db
*.obj
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.sln.docstates
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
*.tlog
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
*.sbr
obj/
###[Rr]elease*/
_ReSharper*/
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
*.opensdf
Zerver.sdf
*.psess
*.ipch
*.cmd
*.res
*.lastbuildstate
Zerver.exe.inter*
*.sdf
_tmp/
*.*.orig
ZerverENU.dll
*_.dll
*[12].dll
*.exp
Zerver_*.exe
Release/Zerver.bsc
packages
Release/Zerver.exe

Release/Zerver.exe
Release/Reflex.dll
Zerver/Release/Zerver.unsuccessfulbuild
Zerver.VC.db
Zerver.VC.VC.opendb
```

Which file is responsible for File Structure in Solution Explorer Window? Which one I need to exclude??

Comment: The solution and project files

Answer (score 0):

At first you should check *.sln file and other project files, E.g. *.csharp.